# Converting year based on months with dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to achieve  such that a number should be rounded to the nearest integer age (ie. if 64 & 3 months = 64, if 64 & 9mths = 65).

This is my code:

```
    var dt = '15/11/2015';
    var roundedAge = Math.round(moment().diff(moment(dt, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'years', true));
    console.log('result:' + Math.round(roundedAge - 0.25));
```

Seems to not work for me.

Comment: The code shown doesn't appear to use the `dt` variable, so the calculation is wrong before it even gets started.

Comment: Sorry i did the edit now to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to round the `Years`, no need to subtract `0.4`

```js
var yrs = moment().add(64 * 12 + 3, "months").diff(moment(), 'years', true);
console.log('result:' + Math.round(yrs));

var yrs2 = moment().add(64 * 12 + 9, "months").diff(moment(), 'years', true);
console.log('result:' + Math.round(yrs2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: This wont work. it should be like -  if 64 & 3 months = 64, if 64 & 9mths = 6

Comment: @aditya063, See updated answer, preciously set to your example

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it.

```
    var floatYears = moment().diff(moment($("#dtDOB").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'years', true);
    var intYears = Math.round(floatYears - 0.25); // Since 0.75 = 9/12 months so shifting the offset.
    $('#calcAge').val(intYears + ' years');
```